# How to save SCollection elements to different BigQuery tables?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I need to save `SCollection` elements into different hourly BigQuery tables on the basis of their timestamps. I tried the following methods -

1. Group elements by `(TableName, Iterable[TableRow])` and then save each `Iterable[TableRow]` to their respective tables using a `BigQueryClient` instance. This does not work as `BigQueryClient` is not serializable.
2. Create an `SCollection[TableName, PCollection[TableRow]]` and then save each `PCollection[TableRow]` to its respective BigQuery table using `BigQueryIO.Write`. To create the `PCollection[TableRow]` objects I use `.map(s => (s._1, sc.pipeline.apply(Create.of(s._2.toList.asJava))))`, where `sc` is an instance of ScioContext. This does not work as `ScioContext` is not serializable.

Is there a way to stream insert elements into different BigQuery tables?

Answer (score 2):

To do this with Scio, you can create a custom output transform that writes to a destination specified by a `DynamicDestinations` object ([Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html)). The table is dynamically determined by some characteristic of the input element, in this case the event time (hour) of the element.

Custom output transform for BigQuery:

```scala
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema
import com.spotify.scio.bigquery.BigQueryUtil
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery._
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.{PCollection, PDone, ValueInSingleWindow}


def saveAsBigQuery(tblPrefix: String,
                   tblSchema: String,
                   writeDisposition: WriteDisposition):
  PTransform[PCollection[TableRow], PDone] = {

  BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
    .to(new DynamicDestinations[TableRow, String] {

      override def getTable(tblSuffix: String): TableDestination = {
        // TODO: construct table name
        val tblName = "%s_%s".format(tblPrefix, tblSuffix)
        new TableDestination(tblName, null)
      }

      override def getDestination(tblRow: ValueInSingleWindow[TableRow]): String = {
        // TODO: determine hourly table suffix based on event time in tblRow object
      }

      override def getSchema(destination: String): TableSchema = {
        BigQueryUtil.parseSchema(tblSchema)
      }
    })
    .withWriteDisposition(writeDisposition)
    .asInstanceOf[PTransform[PCollection[TableRow], PDone]]
}
```

Apply custom output transform using the function above:

```scala
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write


val tblPrefix = "table_prefix"
val tblSchema = "table_schema"  // TODO: this needs to be in valid BigQuery schema format
val writeDisposition = Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

val bqTransform = saveAsBigQuery(
  tblPrefix,
  tblSchema,
  writeDisposition)

// assuming tblRows is an SCollection[TableRow]
tblRows.saveAsCustomOutput("saveAsBigQuery", bqTransform)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Beam, the BigQuery IO transform provides [several methods](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/) for selecting the table based on the current window. I believe that Dataflow 1.9 had similar methods for window-dependent destinations.

Dataflow 2.0 also includes [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html). See the Javadoc for an example that selects the table based on a user ID within each element.

I'm not familiar with Scio, but it seems like exposing the underlying methods from BigQuery IO would be the easiest way to accomplish this.